# jquery.validate.js javascript error

Tags: jquery, validation, tinymce

Trying to run following validation code but jquery.validate.js fails. Did anyone experianced this? I'm using jquery 1.7.2. on Firefox 12.0. After further investigation of the problem I learned that the problem arises only when there are tinymce elements in the form.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#simple_form').validate();
});
</script>
```

Here's the error.

```
classes.split is not a function
classes && $.each(classes.split(' '), function() {
```

Comment: Could you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) please :)

Comment: The page is quite complex so I extracted the form and javascript for validation to jsfiddle. Unfortunately validation worked :/

Comment: I narrowed down the issue. jquery.validate errors when I have tinymce boxes on the page.

Comment: glad to be of assistance haha :)

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that jquery.tinymce.js I was using was a bit different than the one currently hosted on tinymce.com. Replacing that file solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    tinyMCE.triggerSave(true, true);
    $('#simple_form').validate();
});
</script>
```